# How can I get an array in MongoDB returned on Postman?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, postman

[image: mongodb database example]

I included the database schema and I'm trying to fetch the products in the *products * array using Postman.
Here is the base URL: http://localhost:5002/api/v1/store

Also, the backend is fine and connected so http://localhost:5002/api/v1/store?name=Apple would return the first document.

Thanks

Edit: I've added the code that gets executed on endpoint api/v1/store

storeDao.js

```
let store;

export default class StoreDAO {
  static async injectDB(conn) {
    if (store) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      store = await conn.db(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_NS).collection("store");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(
        `Unable to establish a collection handle in storeDAO: ${e}`
      );
    }
  }

  static async getStore({ filters = null, page = 0, storePerPage = 20 } = {}) {
    let query;
    if (filters) {
      if ("name" in filters) {
        query = { $text: { $search: filters["name"] } };
      } else if ("zipcode" in filters) {
        query = { zipcode: { $eq: filters["zipcode"] } };
      }
    }

    let cursor;

    try {
      cursor = await store.find(query);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`);
      return { storeList: [], totalNumStore: 0 };
    }

    const displayCursor = cursor.limit(storePerPage).skip(storePerPage * page);

    try {
      const storeList = await displayCursor.toArray();
      const totalNumStore = await store.countDocuments(query);

      return { storeList, totalNumStore };
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(
        `Unable to convert cursor to array or problem counting documents, ${e}`
      );
      return { storeList: [], totalNumStore: 0 };
    }
  }
}
```

store.controller.js

```
import storeDao from "../dao/storeDAO.js";

export default class StoreController {
  static async apiGetStore(req, res, next) {
    const storePerPage = req.query.storePerPage
      ? parseInt(req.query.storePerPage, 10)
      : 20;
    const page = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page, 10) : 0;

    let filters = {};
    if (req.query.zipcode) {
      filters.zipcode = req.query.zipcode;
    } else if (req.query.name) {
      filters.name = req.query.name;
    }

    const { storeList, totalNumStore } = await storeDao.getStore({
      filters,
      page,
      storePerPage,
    });

    let response = {
      store: storeList,
      page: page,
      filters: filters,
      entries_per_page: storePerPage,
      total_results: totalNumStore,
    };
    res.json(response);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your endpoint currently return? How is it different than what you want? What is the code for that endpoint?

Comment: you need to provide the code that you are executing on the endpoint api/v1/store.

Comment: @imanshu15 I've added the code being executed at the endpoint to the question.

Comment: @user20042973 My endpoint currently can return the mongodb documents sorted by the documents name or its zipcode. I would like it to return the correct document if the searched for term appears in its products array. Added the endpoint code above.

Comment: @Shagufta check the answer posted, if it helps mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation, if the filters parameter is null, the function does not assign a value to the query variable. As a result, when the function tries to execute the query store.find(query), it will throw an error because the query variable is undefined. Try initializing query as an empty object.

```
 let query = {};
```

final code for getStore method should look like this.

```
static async getStore({ filters = null, page = 0, storePerPage = 20 } = {}) {
    let query = {};
    if (filters) {
      if ("name" in filters) {
        query = { $text: { $search: filters["name"] } };
      } else if ("zipcode" in filters) {
        query = { zipcode: { $eq: filters["zipcode"] } };
      }
    }

    let cursor;

    try {
      cursor = await store.find(query);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`);
      return { storeList: [], totalNumStore: 0 };
    }

    const displayCursor = cursor.limit(storePerPage).skip(storePerPage * page);

    try {
      const storeList = await displayCursor.toArray();
      const totalNumStore = await store.countDocuments(query);

      return { storeList, totalNumStore };
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(
        `Unable to convert cursor to array or problem counting documents, ${e}`
      );
      return { storeList: [], totalNumStore: 0 };
    }
  }
```

Comment: In the current implementation, the function is working fine, but what isn't working is if I try to fetch an array from the db; it is filtering it with the name property

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it, turns out you have to add another filter in storeDAO and the storecontroller

storeDao.js

```
let query;
if (filters) {
  if ("name" in filters) {
    query = { $text: { $search: filters["name"] } };
  } else if ("zipcode" in filters) {
    query = { zipcode: { $eq: filters["zipcode"] } };
  } else if ("products" in filters) {
    const product = filters["products"];
    query = { products: { $elemMatch: { name: product } } };
  }
}
```

store.controller.js

```
let filters = {};
if (req.query.zipcode) {
  filters.zipcode = req.query.zipcode;
} else if (req.query.name) {
  filters.name = req.query.name;
} else if (req.query.products) {
  filters.products = req.query.products;
}
```

And then you can call it in your frontend. The documentation for querying arrays from MongoDB in your application can be found here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-array/